# Compiling nano hitting problems during make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, configure, autoconf, automake

I am trying to compile nano and hitting some problems.

Details are as follows -- versions I cannot change (compiling on s390 architecture and don't have access to other versions):

- Nano source version 2.9.7
- Using autoconf version 2.62
- Using automake version 1.10
- Changed configure script so it looks for tooling version 1.10 instead of 1.15 by altering configure line `am__api_version='1.10'`

I run configure, and then I run make. On running make I get the following error:

```
make
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && /bin/sh /u/user/source/nano-2.9.7/missing aclocal-1.10 -I m4
main::scan_file() called too early to check prototype at /workarea/tools/automake/bin/aclocal-1.10 line 604.
configure.ac:27: error: Autoconf version 2.69 or higher is required
configure.ac:27: the top level
autom4te: /usr/local/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 63
aclocal-1.10: autom4te failed with exit status: 63
WARNING: 'aclocal-1.10' is probably too old.
         You should only need it if you modified 'acinclude.m4' or
         'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
         The 'aclocal' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>
         It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>
         <http://www.perl.org/>
FSUM8226 make: Error code 63
```

I note on the first line it says : `CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && /bin/sh /u/user/source/nano-2.9.7/missing aclocal-1.10 -I m4` I don't know how to read this error, given `aclocal-1.10` is on my path and installed. When I run `aclocal-1.10` from my bash shell I get :

```
aclocal-1.10
main::scan_file() called too early to check prototype at /workarea/tools/automake/bin/aclocal-1.10 line 604.
aclocal-1.10: `configure.ac' or `configure.in' is required
```

---

**Update**
I went to line 27 of configure.ac and changed the line
`AC_PREREQ([2.69])` to `AC_PREREQ([2.62])`. Now when the make command is issued it fails with the following error:

```
source/nano-2.9.7: >make
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && /bin/sh /u/user/source/nano-2.9.7/missing aclocal-1.10 -I m4
main::scan_file() called too early to check prototype at /workarea/tools/automake/bin/aclocal-1.10 line 604.
(CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && /bin/sh /u/user/source/nano-2.9.7/missing autoheader)
autoheader: error: AC_CONFIG_HEADERS not found in configure.ac
FSUM8226 make: Error code 1 
make: './config.h.in' removed.
```

Please offer guidance and support around how to work around my system imposed limitations in order to compile my favourite command line editor!

Answer (score 0):

Two easy solutions: Update your autoconf package.

Or fix your timestamps, so that autoconf isn't reinvoked, e.g. by touching all files in the distribution.

```
find . | xargs touch
```

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail what you mean by fix your timestamps? I have not come across this before? Additionally, are you certain that your solutions will fix the problem under the 'UPDATE' section of the question?

Comment: well the update, just means that the developer put the autoconf requirement there for a reason.